# Is it possible to send from integrated to standard address?

Tags: payment-id, payment

i just tried to send Monero, but got an error. apparently the site i want to send from uses a 64-bit integrated address, and the site i want to sent to uses a standard address

is it possible to add a payment ID, and would it work then?

Comment: "...but got an error" <- What error did you get? What wallet are you using? When asking questions, it helps to give as much information as possible rather than being vague.

Comment: I wanted to send from a casino to Kraken.com. the error message was something like "please provide a valid address". i compared the addresses and the one from the casino was longer, so i guess they use an integrated one and kraken a standard one

Comment: Just send to the address Kraken (the recipient) gives you.

Comment: thats what i tried, but get this error, the casino told me the address doesnt exist

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to send from integrated to standard address?

Yes, of course. You simply send from the wallet you created the integrated address. This is because funds aren't technically sent from an address, they are set from a *wallet* that previously received funds.

> ...the site i want to send from uses a 64-bit integrated address

Integrated addresses are not 64-bit. An integrated address is just a standard address with an encrypted 64-bit payment ID embedded in it. This is why integrated addresses are longer than normal addresses.

Comment: How would one go about, sending from an `integrated address` ?

Comment: An integrated address is a standard address with an encrypted payment ID. Thus send from the wallet of that standard address. Also remember, you don't actually send from an address, you send from a wallet.

Comment: Kinda my point. The `integrated address` is the recipient, not the sender. Right?

Comment: The OP asked "Is it possible to send from integrated..." and as a sender wallet can have an integrated address, the question is kind of valid as they received funds to a wallet with an integrated address and they are asking if they can send from this wallet to a standard address, which they can, as answered.